# Discordbot javascript react to mentions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm completely new to Javascript and i would like to make a discord bot. 
I have a bot already running with a few commands, now i would like to add something that posts a reaction whenever someone specific is tagged.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  var user = "123456479879541";
  if(message.mentions.users.id === user) {
    message.channel.send('ok');
  }
});
```

What do i have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

[Message.mentions.users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) is a collection.  You need to determine if your ID is in the collection.  You are comparing equality, which since user is not a collection will always be false.  Replace this with a .has  You can then add a react to the message.  For that, there is a guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages) describing how to get a unicode reaction as shown below.

```
  var user = "123456479879541";
  if(message.mentions.users.has(user)) {
    message.channel.reply('ok');
    message.react('');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Message#react()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react)

So basically for example you could do:

```
client.on('message', message => {
var user = "123456479879541";
const reaction = message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'EMOJI NAME')
    if(message.mentions.users.has(user)) {
        message.channel.reply('ok');
        message.react(reaction)
}});
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, as explained by @Tarazed, `users.id === user` will always evalute to false